# Java MouseListener - Events

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

Does any know if the following is the expected behaviors in terms of what `MouseEvent`s are fired? One seems to be missing or consumed elsewhere.

1. Right-click on `JPanel` and display `JPopupMenu`:

   ```
   MousePressed java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_PRESSED,
     (469,347),absolute(2214,490),button=3,modifiers=Meta+Button3,
     extModifiers=Button3,clickCount=1]

   MouseReleased java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,
     (469,347),absolute(2214,490),button=3,modifiers=Meta+Button3,
     extModifiers=Meta,clickCount=1]

   MouseClicked java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_CLICKED,
     (469,347),absolute(2214,490),button=3,modifiers=Meta+Button3,
     extModifiers=Meta,clickCount=1]
   ```

   So far so good all 3 from button 3 and in correct order
2. With `JPopupMenu` still showing left-click somewhere in the `JPanel` not in the `JPopupMenu`:

   What happened to the `MousePressed` event?

   ```
   MouseReleased java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,
     (452,339),absolute(2197,482),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1]

   MouseClicked java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_CLICKED,
     (452,339),absolute(2197,482),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1]
   ```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the event that causes the popup menu to close has disappeared.

IIRC, exactly how this is implemented changed from 1.5 to 1.6. In 1.5 there is a glasspane, in 1.6 `AWTEventListener`s are used. See `BasicPopupMenuUI` sources for details. It looks as if you can (globally) stop the event being consumed with:

```
UIManager.put("PopupMenu.consumeEventOnClose", false);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be "false" to stop the event from being consumed?